# extending disk partition with other partitions in the way

Tags: partitioning, ssd, disk-space, disk-management

I want to extend my C drive partition after upgrading it, but the 2 partitions have partitions in between them. I'm not sure how to extend it and the extend button is grayed out.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would need to move those two recovery partitions out of the way; and the second one (greyed out) is unmovable. Not a good idea, IMO, I just managed to kill a Win10 installation trying to do just this; to the point that I needed to reset the device wiping out the drive completely.

I'd rather create a new partition on the currently unallocated space. That'd allow you to move stuff to the new partition, freeing up space on C:.

Comment: Yeah, you kind of need to take the OS out of the equation, so that greyed partition is no longer protected. This is the kind of task I'd do on a Mac, using [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) [which, of course, doesn't give a monkey's about what Windows thinks is protected]. This is actually also how I keep clones of my working Windows installs too. Time from drive fail to working machine, <30 minutes.

Comment: @Tetsujin that's interesting. I assumed the same being true for gparted; was sorely dissapoint. In any case I'd be really careful about changing what Windows wants... there's any number of examples of Win dying out when the system partitions are modified. My DR solution is Clonezilla - connect one HDD in, Clonezilla boots, images on the same drive separate partition. Recovery time is also way below half an hour :-) Lin & Win installations, a breeze, but MacBook (somewhat obviously) refuses to boot the Clonezilla drive without hopping through some loops...

Comment: I'm certainly no comprehensive expert on this [& use Macs considerably more than Windows] but I've never known Paragon to 'break' anything. I've used to to move partitions similar to above & clone & restore to dissimilar drives. I tend to be a bit cavalier with what I do to Windows because, even though I do keep 'proper' Windows backups, I never have anything on there I can't afford to lose;) If a drive dies, I just re-image from one I made 6 months ago. No worries. [These days I have no Windows hardware at all, I transitioned to VMs running on Macs; but back when I did, this was how I did it]

Comment: @Tetsujin - actual loud LOL :-D I've been using an early 2013 MacBook for the past couple of years exclusively. It's starting to show its age so I want to retire it entirely to audio processing use - my interface's a TB2 Apollo. I'm slowly migrating to my ideal environment - lightweight Linux (Bunsenlabs) running Windows in a VM for those few apps for which Linux versions don't exist. Tho' that does have some limitations I've not yet managed to overcome. Gotta have a look at that Paragon solution, thanks for the hint :-)